# Which style is best for class-based programming in CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Of these alternatives, which is the best style for class-based programming in CoffeeScript?

```
# Alternative 1
class Person
  constructor: (@name, @age) ->

new Person "Peter", 19

# Alternative 2
class Person
  name: ""
  age: 0
  constructor: (@name, @age) ->

new Person "Peter", 19

# Alternative 3
class Person
  constructor: (@name = "", @age = 0) ->

new Person "Peter", 19


# Alternative 4
class Person
  constructor: (name, age) ->
    @name = name ? ""
    @age = age ? 0

new Person "Peter", 19
```

Comment: What is your criterion for "best"?

Comment: This question should be moved to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @TrevorBurnham: Didn't know about that one. Seems neat!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm. #1 is nice and simple. #3 succinctly shows the expected format of the arguments (though the defaults don't actually make sense—unless you're expecting a person to be named `""`, or to be `0` years old).

What I'd really recommend is using a hash instead:

```
class Person
  constructor: ({@name, @age}) ->

new Person(name: "Peter", age: 19)
```

This frees you from having to memorize the order of the arguments, and makes your instantiation calls more self-documenting.

(I use this approach in some of the examples in *[CoffeeScript: Accelerated JavaScript Development](http://pragprog.com/book/tbcoffee/coffeescript)*.)

Comment: Or more general: Can I specify defaults for the destructuring assignment?

Comment: No, you can't set defaults inline. I'd suggest using the `defaults` method on [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) to fill in default values on your object in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The #1 is ok, but don't determine default values.

#2 and #3 are equivalents, if the class isn't big I would use the #3.

I think #4 is unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 0):

First way is more clear. I always use this approach.